# angularjs factory with $resource doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

This is my angularjs factory :

```
app.factory('lordREST', ['$resource', function($resource){

    return {
        myPost: function(dataSearch, dataParam) {
            $resource(
                urlLordRest, 
                {search: dataSearch, param: dataParam}, 
                {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true, cache: false, headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}}}
            );
        }
    }

}]);
```

and in my controller i use it like that :

```
    lordREST.myPost({dataSearch: dataSearch, dataParam: dataParam}, function(responce) {

        $scope.posts = responce;
        // CONSOLE LOG CONTROL
        // console.log(defineCLC + "data changed");
        console.log($scope.posts);

    });
```

But this action return nothing, what's wrong ?

Comment: Where is `urlLordRest` defined? What is output in your console?

Comment: urlLordRest is defined outside factory and controller. The console.log for $scope.posts is not executed so nothing to put.

Comment: Are you trying to load from a different domain? What do you see in the netwoork?

Comment: Yes, but it's not a issue of network/REST api, it's working good when i used $resource directly in the controller.

Comment: @JoDiii are you sure the signature of your service is correct? You take `function(dataSearch, dataParam)` but you pass in 2 arguments 1 is an object `{dataSearch: dataSearch, dataParam: dataParam}` and other one is action. SO which means in your service `dataParam` is the action and `dataSearch` is the object which has dataParam and dataSearch

Comment: I go to plunkr to show you the code that's working (which is not a factory), sorry for my explanations.

Comment: your parameters are not proper... you need to sent 2 params to `myPost` like `myPost(dataSearch, dataParam)`... then `return $resource()` from `mypost` then register the callback like `myPost(dataSearch, dataParam).then(function(){})`